# Clean way to implement eager loading in Active Record style ORM?

Tags: php, orm, activerecord

I'm in the process of writing a very light-weight ActiveRecord implementation in PHP. I have the basics working, but I want to implement eager loading of at least the one-to-one relationships. I've been brainstorming on a clean way to do this.

If I'm eager loading a single one-to-one relationship, I will have to know the columns for both tables and will have to alias the columns following some convention that will allow me to map the results back into the correct objects.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to alias the columns from each table such that mapping them back to their respective objects is as painless as possible.

My initial thoughts are to alias the base table's columns as "base_column_name" and the related tables columns as "user_email" (if "User" is the name of the related object). Is there a better way to do this that I'm overlooking?

A second option I have considered is to get all of the objects off of the base table, and then gather the related objects in one "WHERE IN" using the keys from the base table. But, would this cause performance problems?

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP uses php's flexible associative arrays in its ActiveRecord implementation.  So a one to many relationship could be

```
array('Tablename'=>array('columnname'=>'columnvalue'), 
      'AssociatedTable'=>array('0', 
             array('columnname'=>'columnvalue')));
```

It does put one more layer in everything so you have to do $data['tablename']['columnname'];